# Checking cookies with an if statement with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to somehow set a cookie using jQuery on my users' first visit, and show a lightbox that will load on page ready.

Once the cookie has been set, if they visit again I want to check if there is a cookie, and if so, *don't* show the lightbox.

I'm using the cookie plugin to help with this.  Can anybody see a problem with my code?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cookie = $.cookie("popup", 1);
    if(cookie == "") { 
        $.fn.colorbox({width:"500px", height:"400px", inline:true, href:"#sell"});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're going to need to check if the cookie exists before creating it.  If you create the cookie before looking for it, it's always going to be there!

So, you're going to want to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (!$.cookie("popup")) { 
        $.fn.colorbox({width:"500px", height:"400px", inline:true, href:"#sell"});
    }
    $.cookie("popup", 1, , {expires: 365});
});
```

I added an expires option because as webdeveloper pointed out in his answer, the [plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/README.md) creates session cookies by default, which is probably not what you want as they are normally deleted when the browser is closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.cookie("popup", 1);
```

Create session cookie. This code doesn't return anything, just `undefined`

Read cookie:

```
$.cookie('popup'); // => "1"
```

Then:

```
>>> undefined == ""

false
```

Documentation: [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)